# How to make a docked control resizeable by the user?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form with a control (a SplitContainer) docked on the right side. The width of the control can be changed in the editor, but not at runtime. What do I have to do to make the docked control resizable by the user?

The rest of the form should be a MdiContainer. So as far as I see, other containers are not usable, because they can not contain MDI children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try docking a `Spliter` control next to your control.